# Could not resolve com.opentok.android.v3:opentok-android-sdk-v3:3.1.3

Tags: mobilesdk, android, salesforce-sdk-android

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalPreProdFcmRelease'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:PreProdFcmDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.opentok.android.v3:opentok-android-sdk-v3:3.1.3.
> Required by:
> project :app > com.salesforce.service:servicesdk:224.1.0 > com.salesforce.service:sos:4.0.9 > com.opentok.android:opentok-android-sdk:2.16.3
> > Could not resolve com.opentok.android.v3:opentok-android-sdk-v3:3.1.3.
> > Could not get resource 'http://tokbox.bintray.com/maven/com/opentok/android/v3/opentok-android-sdk-v3/3.1.3/opentok-android-sdk-v3-3.1.3.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://tokbox.bintray.com/maven/com/opentok/android/v3/opentok-android-sdk-v3/3.1.3/opentok-android-sdk-v3-3.1.3.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

Have the below error with latest salesforce SDK Please can any help

This happens all of sudden from the latest android release while checking

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce SDK for Android seems to use an earlier version of opentok-android-sdk (2.16.3), which has dependency on opentok-android-sdk-v3-3.1.3, which seems to be no longer available (see https://support.tokbox.com/hc/en-us/articles/360059402811-Android-SDK-available-through-maven-central).

The best way to get over this issue would be for Salesforce to update the SDK to use the latest version of opentok SDK, https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.opentok.android/opentok-android-sdk/2.20.1/aar, which does not have a dependency on  opentok-android-sdk-v3-3.1.3.

The workaround is to reach out to Vonage to get a hold of the deprecated opentok-android-sdk-v3-3.1.3 and host it in a private maven repo to use until Salesforce has updated the SDK. (see https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk-samples/issues/394)